# read request attribute inside jsp and display as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jsp

having a div and display some request data

```
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

in javascript like

```
case 1: document.geElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = '<%=request.getAttribute("someString")%>'; 
caes 2: document.geElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "<%=request.getAttribute('someString')%>";
```

this will work fine. but  **someString**  data is comming from server-side and having untrusted data. if **someString** contains **single quote / double quote** in IE7 it shows script error.

```
Error: Unterminated string constant.
```

how to display single quote/double quotes as div data

Comment: perfrom html encoding before sending data will resolve issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSTL` EL

```
case 1: document.geElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "${requestScope.someString}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am solving my problem by using  **escapeJavaScript** method of org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils  class.
  this will encoding html and display ***someString***'s original data

```
document.geElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = '<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript((String)request.getAttribute("someString"))%>';
```